# Limit user access to installing/configuring a plugin?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-access

I'm hiring a freelancer to install a plugin for me and setup a few of the plugin's more complicated settings.

I don't know him personally and would like to limit his access, as there is sensitive information in my WP Admin (sales data, user data, etc) and also just to protect my website from him doing anything potentially malicious.

If I make him a dedicated user account, what is the simplest way to limit his access to install a plugin and change its settings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends entirely on the plugin. You'd need to ask the author.

Comment: Alternate choice would be you ask the help from freelancer using remote computer access facility, you can monitor while he/she do what he/she supposed to do

Comment: @Vishwa that's an interesting idea!

Answer (score 2):

WP doesn't have a built-in way to restrict permissions this granularly. You can either install plugins, or not.

For settings, it depends on where the plugin surfaces its settings. For example, if the settings are under the "Settings" menu, then by default only users with role "administrator" will be able to access and adjust them. (Similarly, any user with role "administrator" will then be able to access and adjust any settings under that menu.) If the plugin's settings are under the "Tools" menu, then by default users with role "editor" will be able to access and adjust them (and any others under that menu).

Installing a plugin should be as straightforward as:

Step 1, load the code: if the plugin is in the WP repository, any admin can search and install it. If it is not in the repository, an admin can upload the plugin's .zip file through the plugin installer.

Step 2, activate: the admin hits "activate" in the plugins listing.

So, you may wish to install the plugin yourself, and then only provide whatever specific access the freelancer will need to adjust settings (keeping in mind that this may also involve FTP access to files if it's a more complex plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the informative response, @WebElaine